# How to pass variable argument in meteor find method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

While doing a find query using the "qnum" variable argument as a value it doesn't return any data. Is it due to the limitation of the variable scope inside an object?

Quiz.js file

```
Questions = new Mongo.Collection("questions");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var qnum = 1;

  Template.question.events({

    "click #submit-btn": function (event, template) {
      //Increment question number when user click on submit button which loads the next question
      qnum += 1;
    }

  });


  Template.body.helpers({
    questions: function (qnum) {
      return Questions.find({qnum: qnum});
    }
  });
}
```

Quiz.html file

```
<div class="quiz">
    <div class="score-board">
        {{#each questions}}
            {{> question}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<template name="question">
    <div class="qa-wrapper" id="{{qnum}}">
        <div class="questions">{{title}}</div>
        <div class="options">
                {{#each options}}
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{this}}"/>{{this}} <br />
                {{/each}}
            <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Questions db collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a207a21c4dbe14cf9837c7"), "qnum" : 1, "title" : "Question 1", "options" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a207b31c4dbe14cf9837c8"), "qnum" : 2, "title" : "Question 2", "options" : [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my hunch is that when you setup an argument to your template helper `questions(qnum)` it expects one, but then in the `{{#each questions}}` bit you don't pass anything. try and remove the `qnum` in in the template.helper def so that it becomes

```
Template.body.helpers({
  questions: function () {
    return Questions.find({qnum: qnum});
  }
});
```

untested. let me know if it works.

To actually get your helper to rerun on button click, you need to make the query parameter (qnum) reactive. Here, Meteor offers various choices, the most obvious one would be to store your `qnum` value in a Session.

```
Session.set("qnum", qnum)
```

and then in the template helper query

```
return Questions.find({qnum: Session.get("qnum") });
```

Comment: Thanks, now its returning the object. However, one more issue i'm facing is that onclick of the button the incremented value is not returning through Questions.find method.

Comment: I update my answer, please check if it works for you.